# Terraform dataproc cluster setup issues

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc, service-accounts, terraform-provider-gcp

I am trying to spin up a private dataproc cluster(1m, 2w) in GCP via terraform. It should also require optional components like docker, anaconda and jupyter. Below are my concerns,

1. I am trying to add image_version and optional_components under software_config as below, Is that doable?

```
    software_config {

      image_version = "1.4.21-debian9"
      override_properties = {
        "dataproc:dataproc.allow.zero.workers"          = "true"
      }
      optional_components = [ "DOCKER", "ANACONDA", "JUPYTER" ]
    }
```

2. If the above not doable, Is using initialize_actions are my only option, like below?

```
    initialization_action {
      script      = "gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/conda/install-conda-env.sh"
      timeout_sec = 500
      }
```

3. How do I assign permissions/keys to the nodes that are being spun up thru terraform. so users can access the nodes with it once provisioned. I tried to use as below,

```
    gce_cluster_config {
      tags    = ["env", "test"]
      network = "${google_compute_network.dp-network.name}"
      internal_ip_only = true
      service_account = "name@name.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    }
```

Appreciate your inputs,

Thank you!

Update: I can spin up a cluster without optional-components specified in the software_config. But If i do, then it is failing with a bug and asked me to report it to bug.

```
gce_cluster_config {
      network               = "${google_compute_network.dataproc-network.name}"
      internal_ip_only      = true
      tags                  = ["env", "staging"]
      zone                  = "${var.zone}"
      service_account       = "${var.service_account}"
      service_account_scopes= [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring",
        "useraccounts-ro",
        "storage-rw",
        "logging-write",
      ]
    }

    # We can define multiple initialization_action blocks    
    initialization_action {
      script      = "gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/stackdriver/stackdriver.sh"
      timeout_sec = 500
    }
    initialization_action {
      script      = "gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/jupyter/jupyter.sh"
      timeout_sec = 500 
    }
```

Comment: Could you expand on #3 as there's several separate things there - user permissions, users accessing nodes, nodes accessing GCP resources like GCS/BQ. It says you tried...did it fail? If so how?

Comment: I mean, whoever added into the respective GCP Project, should have access to all the resources under it. So if I spin up a dataproc cluster under it with the same service account, Should it be enough to get access to nodes? 

I was able to spin up the cluster successful without specifying optional components in software_config. If I did mention then it is throwing a bug and asked me to report it to the github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either 1 or 2 should be fine. What is likely happening is that Terraform provider for Dataproc is out of sync with the API so please file the bug as suggested by the error.

For 3, there's a bit of confusion here - let me try to clear this up. Users will have access to resources (Clusters) when you grant them IAM bindings. This has nothing to do with how you create the Cluster. Either `Editor` or `Dataproc Editor`, or a custom role will allow them to interact with clusters.

It is a good move to set `internal_ip_only` since that makes cluster inaccessible from public internet but it also means `gcloud compute ssh` to individual nodes will not work.

Finally, any user that has permission to interact with the cluster has essentially the same permissions as the service account. This article explains this
https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/iam/dataproc-principals

Comment: Thank you. I reported bug and accepted your answer. appreciated !

Comment: Note that IAP can still be used to gcloud compute ssh into internal instances